# Optional argument in python

Tags: python, argparse

I have a python program that I am trying to add an optional argument to.

If the user doesn't enter anything then I want that value to default to 20. But, if they do enter a value, I will use their value. I wrote that into the program like so:

```
optionParse= argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Change Number of Locations')
optionParse.add_argument('-n', dest='userDefSize')

args=optionParse.parse_args()

if args.n:
    sizeOfList=args.userDefSize
else:
    sizeOfList=20
```

But for some reason it keeps saying:

```
AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'n'
```

What would be the issue here? Is my if statement written incorrectly?

Comment: Seriously, would you just [RTFM](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html) already? It explains how you can set a default value for an argument without faffing around with post-processing. Also, note that you **explicitly specify** the `dest`ination as `userDefSize`, **not** `n`, and you should test for `None` by *identity*, not truthiness.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, add_argument takes a parameter 'default' which will do what you want. [See the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html#combining-positional-and-optional-arguments)

```
optionParse.add_argument('-n', dest='userDefSize', default=20)
```

To answer your second question, the 'dest' parameter redefines where the value passed in is stored in the arg namespace. In this case you told argparse to store the value in `args.userDefSize` instead of `args.n`, so `args.n` doesn't exist.